# Best partitioning strategy to use for postgres query performance improvement?

Tags: postgresql, hash, query-optimization, partitioning

I need to partition a table in postgres for query performance improvement. I have hash partitioned the table on basis of an id_field(primary key). Also tried creating indexes on the partitioned table using columns which are mostly used in the queries on the table. The issue is that most of the queries that are executed on the table consists of combination of columns like text/char value fields, but almost never the id_field(PK) of the table.

Ex table schema:
id_field(char)(PK)  id_1(char)  id_2(char)  some_string_field(text)  some_descriptor_field(char)  some_enum_field(char)

Most of the queries involve use of id_1 with combination of 'some_string_field' or 'some_descriptor_field'. Or queries involving just 'some_string_field' with 'some_descriptor_field' with 'some_enum_field'.

Is any partitioning strategy going to help improve the query performance? If yes, which partitioning strategy should I go with?

I have tried hash partitioning the table on basis of the id_field(PK) and created indexes on the table using columns that are mostly used in the queries.
The performance seems to be the same on a non-partitioned indexed table when compared with this partitioned indexed table. (Just used 10-12k records to do the comparison).

Comment: That is impossible to answer without knowing your actual queries. Queries that fetch a few rows from the table will **always** become *slower* with partitioning, and most other queries will become slower too. You can only expect performance gains with certain analytical queries or with queries that execute sequential scans on large tables.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your queries, table definitions, index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.